# how to retrieve key with certain value that has value as a tuple(python)

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'Stephen Curry': [(22.6, 5.1, 3.4)], 'Draymond Green': [(16.5, 10.3, 6.3)], 'Lebron James': [(29.7, 11.3, 8.9)]})
```

Each value corresponds to a catergory in this case the format is (pts,reb,assists)  I'm trying to retrieve the max value of pts,reb, and assists between each player and write to a file. I'm having trouble getting the max value to correspond with the correct key.

```
def writeMVP(myfile,statAverages):
  myfile = open(myfile,"w")
  myfile.write("NBA Finals Stats")
  index = 0
  for item in statAverages:
     maxstat= max([avg[0][index] for avg in statAverages.values()])
     index = index + 1
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like maybe you are intending to say "item" instead of "statAverages" in the loop body?

Comment: Can you give us the output of this code?

Comment: Your dictionary has list values which contain one tuple each, is this the right structure for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would just find the key corresponding to the max value like this:

```
In [13]: max_pts_player = max(stats, key=lambda x:stats[x][0][0])

In [14]: max_pts_player
Out[14]: 'Lebron James'

In [15]: max_reb_player = max(stats, key=lambda x:stats[x][0][1])

In [16]: max_reb_player
Out[16]: 'Lebron James'

In [17]: max_assits_player = max(stats, key=lambda x:stats[x][0][2])

In [18]: max_assits_player
Out[18]: 'Lebron James'
```

And then you can just retrieve the max stat using the player name and tuple index that corresponds to the stat:

```
In [19]: max_pts = stats[max_pts_player][0][0]

In [20]: max_pts
Out[20]: 29.7
```

But if you want to start out with the stat,

```
In [5]: max_pts
Out[5]: 29.7

In [6]: list(filter(lambda k:stats[k][0][0] == max_pts, stats))Out[6]: ['Lebron James']
```

This way may be better if more than one player can have the maximum stat.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so to the best of my understanding, this is what I came up with:

```
d = {'Stephen Curry': [(23.6, 5.1, 3.4)], 'Draymond Green': [(16.5, 10.3, 6.3)], 'Lebron James': [(29.7, 11.3, 8.9)]}

lst_tuples = sorted(d.items())

max_pts = max(lst_tuples, key = lambda x: x[1][0][0])
max_rebs = max(lst_tuples, key = lambda x: x[1][0][1])
max_assists = max(lst_tuples, key = lambda x: x[1][0][2])

print_stat_1 = "Max points player: {0}, with a score of {1}.\n" \
               .format(max_pts[0], max_pts[1][0][0])

print_stat_2 = "Max rebs player: {0}, with a score of {1}.\n" \
               .format(max_rebs[0], max_rebs[1][0][1])

print_stat_3 = "Max assists player: {0}, with a score of {1}.\n" \
               .format(max_assists[0], max_assists[1][0][2])

with open("best_player_stats.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("NBA Finals Stats\n")
    text_file.write("----------------\n")
    text_file.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (print_stat_1, print_stat_2, print_stat_3))

with open("best_player_stats.txt","r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Which prints out:

```
NBA Finals Stats
----------------
Max points player: Lebron James, with a score of 29.7.

Max rebs player: Lebron James, with a score of 11.3.

Max assists player: Lebron James, with a score of 8.9.
```

If i have not done the right thing, please let me know in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Stephen Curry': [(22.6, 5.1, 3.4)],
 'Draymond Green': [(16.5, 10.3, 6.3)],
 'Lebron James': [(29.7, 11.3, 8.9)]}


max_pts_player = list(reversed(sorted(data, key=lambda x: data[x][0][0])))[0]
max_reb_player = list(reversed(sorted(data, key=lambda x: data[x][0][1])))[0]
max_assits_player = list(reversed(sorted(data, key=lambda x: data[x][0][2])))[0]

with open("nba_stats.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("NBA Finals Stats\n")
    f.write("Maximum points player is " + max_pts_player + ", with a points of " + str(data[max_pts_player][0][0]) + ".\n")
    f.write("Maximum rebs player is" + max_reb_player  + ", with a points of " +  str(data[max_reb_player][0][1]) + ".\n")
    f.write("Maximum assits player is" + max_assits_player + ", with a points of " + str(data[max_reb_player][0][2]) + ".\n")
```